# Error connecting from Python to Db2 through pyodbc

Tags: python, db2, jupyter, pyodbc

I installed the Db2 ODBC driver in Windows 10 following [these instructions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/t0023866.html). I extracted the driver folder in `C:\tools\db2cli\` and run `db2cli install -setup` from the `bin` folder.

This seems to have worked fine, as the ODBC driver was registered in Windows:

[image]

But when I try to connect from `Jupyter` I get this error:

```
server = 'localhost' 
database = 'mydb' 
username = 'db2inst1' 
password = 'abc123' 
driver = 'IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - C_tools_db2cli'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={' + driver +'};SERVER='
         + server + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' 
         + username + ';PWD=' + password + ';PROTOCOL=TCPIP;PORT=50000' )
```

> ---
>
> Error                                     Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 4 password = 'abc123'
> 5 driver = 'IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - C_tools_db2cli'
> ----> 6 conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={' + driver +'};SERVER='
> 7          + server + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';UID='
> 8          + username + ';PWD=' + password + ';PROTOCOL=TCPIP;PORT=50000' )
>
> Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C  An unexpected
> system error occurred.  SQLSTATE=58004\r\n (-1042) (SQLDriverConnect);
> [HY000] [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C  An unexpected system error
> occurred.  SQLSTATE=58004\r\n (-1042)')

I unsuccessfully tried to find the error codes to find a solution. What should be looked at to fix this problem?

Note: I added `C:\tools\db2cli\bin` to the PATH but still get the same error.

Comment: What's the reason for using pyodbc, instead of the `ibm_db` interface ? (`pip install ibm_db`) and using `ibm_db.connect()` ?

Comment: @mao, I have the same problem with ibm_db trying to connect with `conn = ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=mydb;HOSTNAME=localhost;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=db2inst1;PWD=abc123", "", "")` I get `SQLCODE=-1042on: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.  SQLSTATE=58004`

Comment: Use `HOSTNAME=localhost;` not `SERVER=` in the connection string. It means the installation (of the CLI driver) is somehow misconfigured. Did you install the CLI driver as an Administrator? Leaving python aside temporarily, does the CLI driver operate by itself? Create and Configure the `db2dsdriver.cfg` file as per documentation, and test with the `db2cli -connect -dsn XXX -user YYY -passwd ZZZ`  . This may give more details.

Comment: @mao db2cli works well, I can connect and run a select

Comment: If the `db2cli connect -dsn ...` succeeds, and python fails using that same db2cli, then edit your question to specify the modified connection string (mask the credentials), the text output of `python -V` and the text output of `pip show ibm_db`.  You can see what is happening under the covers by using the tracing facilities of db2trc (refer to documentation) to capture trace, dump it, and format convert the binary output into readable text.

Comment: Additionally, ensure that the final character of the connection string is also a semicolon.

Comment: @mao, I'm getting a different error now, maybe because I created the `db2dbdriver.cfg` ? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65688716/cannot-connect-to-db2-from-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was caused by a defect in clidriver for some specific configurations on Microsoft Windows.

You can workaround this by ensuring that the PATH does not have any other Db2-products on it (except for `clidriver\bin`), and then ensuring to add two additional directories to the PATH before launching python. These are the fully qualified pathnames to these directories:

```
clidriver\bin\icc64
clidriver\bin\amd64.vc12.crt
```

IBM should at some point deliver a fix for IT34327.

Answer (score 0):

SERVER= is for the already cataloged database

otherwise you must use: HOSTNAME=  if you want to specify full DSN.
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Db2onCloud?topic=Db2onCloud-con_program&locale=fr