# Cannot connect to Db2 from python

Tags: python, db2

I installed `ibm_db` in python with `pip install ibm_db` and created a `db2dsdriver.cfg` file with the following content:

```
<configuration>
  <dsncollection>
    <dsn alias="BANK0002" name="BANK0002" host="localhost" port="50000"/>
  </dsncollection>
  <databases>
    <database name="BANK0002" host="BANK0002" port="50000"/>
  </databases>
</configuration>
```

Running this command line I can connect with the database and allows me to run a select statement with no issues:

```
db2cli execsql -user DB2INST1 -passwd xxxxx -dsn bank0002
```

The problem is that I cannot connect from Python:

```
conn = ibm_db.connect("UID=DB2INST1;PWD=xxxxxx;DATABASE=bank0002;
       HOSTNAME=localhost;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;", "", "")
```

throws:

> SQLCODE=-30082n: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30082N  Security processing
> failed with reason "17" ("UNSUPPORTED FUNCTION").  SQLSTATE=08001

What is this problem and how to fix it?

```
python -V
Python 3.8.5


pip show ibm_db
Name: ibm-db
Version: 3.0.2
Summary: Python DBI driver for DB2 (LUW, zOS, i5) and IDS
Home-page: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ibm_db/
Author: IBM Application Development Team
Author-email: opendev@us.ibm.com
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: c:\tools\miniconda3\envs\env38\lib\site-packages
```

Comment: The connection string should use `UID=...` instead of `USER=...`, and `PWD=...` instead of `PASSWD=...`.     .  Also what is the conda version?  (There were reports in the past of issues involving ibm_db with conda, but most are resolved). Please specify if you tried with Admin mode (for install , as well as run, and if there is any different symptom).

Comment: I fixed UID and PWD and now I get the same error I got before `SQLCODE=-1042on: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.  SQLSTATE=58004`

Comment: conda version is 4.9.2, running jupyter as admin throws the same error

Comment: @mao see [here](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb), could it be that the python version 3.8.5  is not supported? It says <= 3.8

Comment: Last year I had to build my own ibm_db with Conda 4.8.5 to get it to work with Conda on Win10. I've not upgraded Conda since then. I suspect you may need to do the same. Your issue is Conda related, I believe. Easy to prove if you try on a workstation that does not have conda, but has python 3.8.

Comment: I reinstalled everything, including miniconda, the db2 client and the ibm_db package, still get the same error. This works fine: `db2cli validate -connect -dsn mydb -user DB2INST1 -passwd xxxxx` and also JDBC connections. The problem has to do with python, as you said. I know how to download a GitHub project, but any ideas how to create the package manually?

Comment: For Conda 4.8.5 (aka 2020.07), I successfully built ibm_db by following  https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs-skeleton.html  , and also the related pages. After build, I used conda to install from locally built package, and this allowed successful connection to Db2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the python build as delivered by miniconda / anaconda, and this may be the determining factor.

A workaround is to use conda to build ibm_db locally and to install the newly built package from local. Other workarounds may be possible.

The instructions for building conda packages and installing them are [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs-skeleton.html) and related pages.

For Win10 x64 20H2 with anaconda 2020.11 (4.9.2) the following commands let me use `python ibm_db` module to connect to Db2, at least from the anaconda prompt.

- Install Anaconda 2020.11 for Microsoft Windows x64.
- In a administrator-mode Anaconda3 prompt window run these commands (ensuring each command completes successfully before running the next one):
- `conda install conda-build git anaconda-clean m2-patch`
- `conda update conda conda-build git m2-patch`
- `cd /d %userprofile%`
- if directory `ibm_db` exists the rename it or remove it.
- `conda skeleton pypi ibm_db`
- `conda-build ibm_db`
- `conda install --use-local ibm_db`

If you now run `conda list`, it's output should contain `ibm_db` module, and the python (3.8.5) will connect to Db2 , at least when used in the anaconda prompt window.

If you continue to get the same SQL1042C symptom, verify that the PATH has no other Db2-products (other than `clidriver\bin`) on it, and then add two additional directories to the PATH before launching python. These are the fully qualified pathnames to `clidriver\bin\icc64`  and `clidriver\bin\amd64.vc12.crt` (or whatever the amd64.vc.XX.crt is present under clidriver\bin).  This is not normally needed, there is is a defect in clidriver for some specific configurations that makes it necessary, and IBM should deliver a fix at some future time (IT34327).

Comment: I followed your instructions and I could generate the package with no issues, but I'm still getting the same error: `conn = ibm_db.connect("UID=DB2INST1;PWD=xxxxxx;DATABASE=bank0002;HOSTNAME=localhost", "", "")  SQLCODE=-1042on: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.  SQLSTATE=58004`

Comment: I tried this from a simple python program in Visual Studio Code, and from Jupyter, I get the same error. What if I install miniconda for python 3.7 instead of 3.8, will that make a difference?

Comment: As I have proved, conda 4.9.22 built ibm_db 3.0.2 successfully connects to Db2 on Win10. Verify with python at the Anaconda command line (i.e. not from jupyter or VS-Code ).  If you get the same symptom, follow the documented procedure for `db2trc` , dump and format its output and study it for details.

Comment: Same symptom running at the Anaconda command line, will continue with `db2trc`

Comment: I did the trace, one thing that I see repeatedly is `SQLO_INSTALLATION_NAME_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: Find the -1042, and carefully study what leads up to it. Additionally, before running python, check the PATH, to verify no other Db2 product is on the PATH.

Comment: I see this before the -1042, `cryptDynamicLoadGSKitCrypto exit [rc = 0x90000076 = -1879048074]` I also posted the trace file [here](http://sofiana.com/trace.flw)

Comment: Please add to PATH before launching python the fully qualified pathnames for clidriver\bin\icc64  and clidriver\bin\amd64.vc12.crt   (or whatever amd64.vcXX.crt directory is present).   Also ensure no other Db2 product directory is on the PATH.

Comment: That fixed the problem, it works including the select and fetch rows. But I had to keep the clidriver\bin folder in the PATH, otherwise I got a DLL not found error

Comment: One additional comment, to register the ODBC with `db2cli install -setup` I had to remove the two folders you told me to add, otherwise it ended OK but did nothing.